# Verilog and ASM implementation

Tags: verilog, fsm

In the question below,

The ASM chart shows that value of `q_next` is compared to 0 to proceed to next state but before `q_next` is compared, the value of q is already updated with `q_next`, so if we compare the value of q with 0, will the results be same in terms of timing and other parameters?

Also what should be the types of `q_next and q` ? Should they be reg or wire?

I have attached the screenshots of the ASM chart and the Verilog code. I also don't understand the timing implications of conditional box (in general, can't we put the output of a conditional box in a separate state which doesn't depend on the output of the conditional box)?,

like when in the wait1 state, we check the value of sw and if true, we decrement the counter and then check if counter has reached to zero and then asser db_tick. I want to understand the time flow when we move from wait1 and increment counter and assert db_tick. Are there any clock cycles involved between these stages, that is moving from a state to a conditional box?

Also in the verilog code, we use `q_load` and `q_tick` to control the counter. Why these signals are used when we can simply control the counter in the states?

Is it done to make sure that the FSM (control path) controls the counter (data path)? Please explain. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> In the question below, the ASM chart shows that value of q_next is
>   compared to 0 to proceed to next state but before q_next is compared,
>   the value of q is already updated with q_next, so if we compare the
>   value of q with 0, will the results be same in terms of timing and
>   other parameters?

No. When `q_next` has a value of 0, `q` still contains a value of 1 until it's updated on the next positive clock edge. If you check for `q==0`, you will spend an extra clock cycle in each wait state.

> Also what should be the types of q_next and q? Should they be reg or
>   wire?

Either. `reg` types (like `q_reg`) mean they're assign a value in an `always` block, while `wire` types (like `q_next`) are assigned using the `assign` statement or as the output of a submodule.

> I also don't understand the timing implications of conditional box (in
>   general, can't we put the output of a conditional box in a separate
>   state which doesn't depend on the output of the conditional box)?,
>   like when in the wait1 state, we check the value of sw and if true, we
>   decrement the counter and then check if counter has reached to zero
>   and then asser db_tick. I want to understand the time flow when we
>   move from wait1 and increment counter and assert db_tick.

Here's the flow of operations for a single clock cycle while in the `wait1` state:

- Is `SW==1`? If not, do nothing else, and go to state `zero`. Those operations will be done on the next cycle.
- If `SW==1`, compute `q_next`, and assign that value to `q` for the next cycle.
- Is `q_next==0`? If not, remain in `wait1` for the next cycle and repeat.
- Otherwise, assert `db_tick=1` for this clock cycle, and go to state `one`.

If you split up the two conditionals into two separate states, counting down to 0 will take twice as long.

> Are there any clock cycles involved between these stages, that is
>   moving from a state to a conditional box?

Based on the diagram, all operations (comparing `sw`, subtracting from `q`, etc) within a given state - that is, one of the dotted-line boxes - are performed in a single clock cycle.

> Also in the verilog code, we use q_load and q_tick to control the
>   counter. Why these signals are used when we can simply control the
>   counter in the states? Is it done to make sure that the FSM (control
>   path) controls the counter (data path)?

You could do it that way too. Just be sure to assign a value to `q_next` in the `default` case to prevent latching. Splitting the data path and control path into separate `always` blocks/`assign` statements does improve readability though, IMO.